# Need help finding out whether this my circuit will work as intended (new to electronics)

Tags: arduino, pcb-design

This is my first time designing a simple circuit. I made one that enables an Arduino Uno to control a step motor by turning on various coils. It has 4 inputs that go to the Arduino, and as each coil is turned on, an LED should light up as an indicator for this. I am using the IC 'ULN2003APG' as the central IC.

The section that is circled is the 5 pins for the 28BYJ-48 motor.

Does/will this circuit work as intended?

[image: The section that is circled is the 5 pins for the 28BYJ-48 motor.]

Comment: Can you post the schematic?

Comment: schematic or it didn't happen.

Comment: Pro tip: don't put your designators (like "U1") where you won't be able to read them after the chip is soldered down to the board.

Comment: What do the left ends of the resistors connect to?

Comment: @PeterBennett A vertical trace, printed in blue. It lines up with one of the gridlines, so it's easy to miss.

Comment: What current are you pumping through those traces? You may want to beef them up, you have the space for it.

Comment: Why not rotate those resistors?

Comment: I would use wider traces for the motor connections...

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious problems.

1) The most important - you need a signal ground connection which will connect to the Arduino ground. If you are using a 5 volt supply and sharing it with the Arduino you're all set, but there are many different ways to connect to the many different Arduino models, so this is not guaranteed. Add a signal ground and use it.

2) The resistor common should be connected to V+, not V-, and the LED polarities should be reversed. That way, when an output is pulled low and current is flowing through the winding, the corresponding LED will be lit.